# What is slowest to render, separate images drawn in via absolute positioning, or a complete image?

Tags: html, css

I have on my site a bunch of "cards" that are just jpg images right now, but I'm thinking of switching this out for a html/css rendered solution, which would require me to position a lot of small icons on a background and then add some stylish text on it.

The problem is, I don't know how to measure which method is faster for the client or the server.

I threw together an example to illustrate (yes it's ugly).

Full image (111kb):

[image]

Rendering via html/css:

https://jsfiddle.net/u5osqyfy/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="background" src="http://i.imgur.com/qCxyd9v.jpg">
  <img class="icon one" src="http://i.imgur.com/c5Qx3x7.png">
  <img class="icon two" src="http://i.imgur.com/4G8xUeM.png">
  <img class="icon three" src="http://i.imgur.com/9Kips1U.png">
  <img class="icon four" src="http://i.imgur.com/0utE9VD.png">
  <img class="icon five" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ej7w0pA.png">
  <img class="icon six" src="http://i.imgur.com/9EdnWnW.png">
  <div class="text">
    How do I measure how much "juice" this takes to render?
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
}

.icon.one {
  left: 10px;
  top: 20px;
}

.icon.two {
  left: 140px;
  top: 20px;
}

.icon.three {
  left: 270px;
  top: 20px;
}

.icon.four {
  left: 400px;
  top: 20px;
}

.icon.five {
  left: 140px;
  top: 150px;
}

.icon.six {
  left: 270px;
  top: 150px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 350px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

The background is 73 kb and the images are 7kb each for a total of 73 + 42 = 115 kb.

But sometimes a few of the icons are the same as each other, which would bring down the total in terms of raw kbs, so then it becomes a question of how much the positioning costs...

How do I go about actually measuring what's best? Because I imagine this is a question with no set answer but rather something that needs to be reviewed on a case-by-case basis.

So, 1) How do I measure this?

or

2) Can it be stated directly that it doesn't much matter?

Comment: Without reading: You can view performance in Google Chrome's inspector under the Timeline tab if you're willing to try both.  In general, the less calls to a server the better - so less images formatted properly will load faster than anything more.  Check your CSS file size, the more you write, the larger it is and it ALL has to load for it to work.  Is this for a bigger purpose? These days 115kb + CSS size will not be a huge load for any system

Comment: Definitely use Chrome's inspector like @ntgCleaner mentioned, but I'm curious as to why you are worried about 115kb worth of images. Are these icons used 30-40 times on a page, or is there a concern about staying under a specific filesize?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screenshot of my measurement on your fiddle using Chrome Dev Tools.

[image: Network tab in Chrome Dev Tool comes very handful in this case!]

As you can see, fragmenting the image in separate assets is a good solution because it results in **many concurrent http requests**, which is generally better at the same bandwidth.

By the way, it's hard to define a thumb rule in such cases, you'll have to decide on case-by-case basis.

In this particular scenario, I'll suggest the "many-assets-via-css" approach.

Comment: What if there are twenty of these on the page? The concurrent requests don't matter as much then, right?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:  You can measure any website load if you have an inspector to do so.  I would suggest going into Google Chrome, opening the inspector and clicking on the "Timeline" tab.  Once there, Either refresh the page (Or press record in the top left corner of the window, then refresh) and it will show you the load times for various items.

For example, this page loads in 2.72s.  77.11ms Loading, 456.61 Scripting, 191.89 Rendering, 162.97 Painting, 163.16 Other.  This way you can see what the biggest pain points of your page are.  In this example loading this page, the biggest pain point is the Scripting - but honestly, it's only half a second, so there's nothing to worry about.

Answer 2: Your file sizes are so small.  Assuming you don't need to load a lot of the same example and this is the only thing loading on the page - No, this does not matter.  115kb + CSS size (usually tiny also) is far too small to notice a difference in loading time on most modern machines.  If you have more images than the example above, the problem gets exponentially more problematic.  So then it depends on how many unique images you're calling and how many duplicates you're calling.  If it's still a lot of images, you may want to start combining images and saving them properly (at a small size) so it is less calls to a server.

**UPDATE**
Here's an ugly example of using a single icon with CSS to determine the diamonds: https://jsfiddle.net/g4stvufk/

Of course the icon should have the diamond shine included to look like yours

HTML

```
<div class="diamond">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWeXerY.png">
</div>
```

css

```
.diamond {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 65px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
.diamond:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -65px;
    top: 65px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 65px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: red;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The best advice I can give is "Reuse, Reuse, Reuse"  Whatever you can find to reuse (like the icon and the shine), reuse it.

Comment: There are 40+ of these on the page, so my point wasn't that it was too small to matter, but simply that the two methods are too similar to matter.

Comment: @Yeats, Ah I see.  Well, the larger or more elements you need to load, the bigger the problem becomes.  How many unique images are there? how many duplicate images are there out of the 40+ of them?

Comment: None of the 40 are duplicates, but the icons on them are, and the icons are shared across all of them also, so there is only need to load ten of them actually.

Comment: If only icons are duplicates, you may be able to get away with sticking with a SINGLE png and using CSS to style the diamond behind them.  This would save time since you only have to make a single call to the CSS and a single call to the image - only 2 calls, vs 41.  It will make your CSS larger, but it should save time in the actual call of the file

Answer (score 0):

Multiple http requests will generally always be slower than using one request. Try using an image sprite - only one http request then using css to position on the page. 
You can even use build tools like Grunt or Gulp to automate this piece for you too, including reducing the image file size with losless compression tools like TinyPNG.com (these can also be included as API calls in your grunt/gulp tasks) - one stop automation.